# c stream buffer

Tags: stream, buffer

I am using C and need a stream buffer mechanism that I can write arbitrary bytes two and read bytes from.  I would prefer something that is platform independent (or that can at least run on osx and linux).  Is anyone aware of any permissive lightweight libraries or code than I can drop in?

I've used buffers within libevent and I may end up going that route, but it seems overkill to have libevent as a dependency when I don't do any sort of event based io.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind depending on C++ and possibly some bits of STL, you can use std::stringstream. It shouldn't be too difficult to write a thin C wrapper around it.

Comment: `s/STL/the C++ Standard Library`. The STL has no `std` namespace.

Comment: @Tomalak: I probably actually meant "something which uses templates" (I'm not sure how much of `std::basic_string<>`/etc increases your code size via template instantiations). But `std::vector` has always worked for me...

Comment: I think you misunderstood me.

Answer (score 0):

Is `setbuf(3)` (and its aliases) the 'mechanism' you are searching for?

Please consider the following example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char buf[256];
  setbuffer(stderr, buf, 256);
  fprintf(stderr, "Error: no more oxygen.\n");
  buf[1] = 'R';
  buf[2] = 'R';
  buf[3] = 'O';
  buf[4] = 'R';
  fflush(stderr);
}
```